# do i have to use the same oAuth2Client that was used to create the redirect URL to call google calendar api or can i use a new instance

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

trying to do Google calendar api call from express server as shown in `node js` quickguide of Google calendar but i get *ERR*:

> " Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup "

. the only difference from the quickguide is that i use newly cretaed `oAuth2Client` object when creating redirect *URL* and another instance of `oAuth2Client` for *Google Calendar API*

Comment: i found what was wrong in my code.
        const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: oAuth2Client});
instead of the code above which is the right one i wrote it like:
      const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', oAuth2Client});

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. in the future.